# Transition для input - range, для плавного перемещения

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

Возможно-ли добавить transition к ползунку, чтобы он смог передвигаться плавно? Если да, то как?

Comment: Добавить `transition` возможно, но работать не будет. Переходы изменений числовых значений атрибутов не стилизуются через CSS.

Comment: Вариантом реализации может быть инкремент значения инпута в коллбэке `requestAnimationFrame` (советую глянуть на MDN пока ожидаешь ответы), но есть проблема с тем что подобные вещи мешают пользовательскому вводу (изменению значения вручную).

Comment: если нарисуете свой - то можно

Comment: [вот пример](https://Range-1.vova2020.repl.co) Это конечно не то но все же анимация